# What is the audible difference between a song written in A Natural Minor scale and a C Major scale?

Tags: scales

I started taking music classes to try to learn some theory.  I learnt there's something called a major scale.  But today, Youtube recommended a video called Minor Scales, so I clicked on it. The video mentioned something called natural minor scale, and as far as I can see, is exactly the same notes as its major scale counter part.

My question is if there is a song or piece of music written in C major scale, is it synonymous to say it is written in A natural minor scale?  If not, then what is the audible difference between a piece of music written in C major vs A natural minor if they all use exactly the same notes?